# Is there a way to catch all invokations of hardlink creation and replace them with symbolic links?

Tags: linux, symbolic-link, hardlink

Assume I have a program or build script (consider it a blackbox) which is creating hardlinks and run on Linux (Debian 7.4). If I want to experiment and find out whether the program would work with symbolic links as well without touching it, how would I do that?

I imagine something like

```
magicwrapper make
```

Maybe it's possible to intercept system calls for hardlink creation and replace them with symlink creation.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this, which creates a logging wrapper script to replace `ln` (go ahead and copy-and-paste it):

```
l=$(which ln)
mv $l $l.bak
cat <<'EOF' >$l
#!/bin/bash
if grep -Eqw -- -s <<<"$@"
  echo "Symbolic link created by command: ln $@" >>/tmp/link_log
fi
<sed>
EOF
sed "s/<sed>/$l.bak/" -i $l
chmod +x $l
```

Now you can run `make`, and your new `ln` will log symbolic link creation to `/tmp/link_log`, and it **will** still create links just as it should, since it passes its arguments on to the *real* `ln`.

To put everything back:

```
l=$(which ln)
mv $l.bak $l
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**

As pointed out in the comments, this is not a catch-all.
Here is a better way of doing it:

```
cat <<'EOF' >/tmp/symlink_only.c
#include <unistd.h>
int link(const char *path1, const char *path2)
{
    return symlink(path1, path2);
}
int linkat(int olddirfd, const char *oldpath, int newdirfd, const char *newpath, int flags)
{
    return symlink(oldpath, newpath);
}
gcc -Wall -fPIC -shared -o /tmp/symlink_only.so /tmp/symlink_only.c -ldl
```

And then you can run your `<program>` like this: `LD_PRELOAD=/tmp/symlink_only.so <program>`. It should work; I've tested it with `ln`.

Then to put everything back: `rm /tmp/symlink_only.{c,so}`.

Comment: Replace system `ln`? and hope nothing else is running that uses it at that time... wouldn't it be safer to make a local `ln` and set  your PATH to that one? if your make system uses hard coded paths, you're SOL, but at least your system isn't gorked

Comment: This will only replace the  `ln` executable. Anything that uses the `link` system call will not be affected.

Comment: @Bob If it is a script, my code should work fine. If it is a program, `strace` would be very easy to use.

Comment: @Bob See my edit.